# Control Mouse using Gesture

Tags: python, opencv, gesture

When I run the code below, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "path\gesture_mouse.py", line 63, in
>
> ```
>    cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), (w+h)/4, (0, 0, 255), 2)
> ```
>
> TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
>
> ```
>   [ WARN:0] terminating async callback
> ```

I tried assigning the center and the radius separately pre-defined.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
import wx

mouse = Controller()

app = wx.App(False)

(sx, sy) = wx.GetDisplaySize()
(camx, camy) = (320, 240)

lowerBound = np.array([33, 80, 40])
upperBound = np.array([102, 255, 255])

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

kernelOpen = np.ones((5, 5))

kernelClose = np.ones((20, 20))

pinchFlag = 0

while True:

    ret, img = cam.read()

    img=cv2.resize(img, (340, 220))

    # convert BGR to HSV
    imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    # create the Mask
    mask = cv2.inRange(imgHSV, lowerBound, upperBound)
    # morphology
    maskOpen = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernelOpen)
    maskClose = cv2.morphologyEx(maskOpen, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernelClose)

    maskFinal = maskClose
    conts, h = cv2.findContours(maskFinal.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    if len(conts) == 2:
        if pinchFlag == 1:
            pinchFlag = 0
            mouse.release(Button.left)
        x1, y1, w1, h1 = cv2.boundingRect(conts[0])
        x2, y2, w2, h2 = cv2.boundingRect(conts[1])
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x1+w1, y1+h1), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x2, y2), (x2+w2, y2+h2), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cx1 = x1+w1/2
        cy1 = y1+h1/2
        cx2 = x2+w2/2
        cy2 = y2+h2/2
        cx = (cx1+cx2)/2
        cy = (cy1+cy2)/2
        cv2.line(img, (cx1, cy1), (cx2, cy2), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 2, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        mouseLoc = (sx-(cx*sx/camx), cy*sy/camy)
        mouse.position = mouseLoc
        while mouse.position != mouseLoc:
            pass
    elif len(conts) == 1:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(conts[0])
        if pinchFlag == 0:
            pinchFlag = 1
            mouse.press(Button.left)
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cx = x+w/2
        cy = y+h/2
        cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), (w+h)/4, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        mouseLoc = (sx-(cx*sx/camx), cy*sy/camy)
        mouse.position = mouseLoc
        while mouse.position != mouseLoc:
            pass
    cv2.imshow("cam", img)
    cv2.waitKey(5)
```

I was expecting that when two green color objects appear in the frame they will be scribed in a blue box, and a blue line from the center of the two box will appear where a red dot will be present signifying the location of the cursor(mouse).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error says, the function needs int's as input, but you input floats. This is because the values are the result of division calculations.

```
print(type(10))      #<class 'int'>
print(type(5))       #<class 'int'>
print(type(10/5))    #<class 'float'>
print(10/5)          #2.0
```

The solution is the convert the calculated values to integers:

```
cv2.circle(img, (int(cx), int(cy), int((w+h)/4), (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution but now as soon as I run the program the camera stops responding.

Comment: Probably due to this code: `while mouse.position != mouseLoc:
            pass`. It is a while loop that does nothing, so it runs forever. The values being unequal could also be caused by int/float. To debug try this `if mouse.position != mouseLoc:
            print("Mouse pos/loc unequal. mouse pos: " + str(mouse.position) + " - mouse loc: " + str(mouseLoc))` This will give you a message with values to compare visually, but not freeze up program execution.

Comment: @Aditya this is the answer to your question. Consider marking it as answer. If you have follow-up questions, you can always open a new question.